# Formatting Dictionary Within Object in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, formatting, python-2.6, truncate

I have a piece of code that has creates a dictionary `Enzyme_dict` and then fills that dictionary with objects (from `class Enzyme`). One of the attributes of that class of objects is itself a dictionary (`self._specif`). The dictionary that makes up that attribute is filled up with several values, all equal to `1.0/5`. Because of machine precision, this value gets printed as `0.20000000000000001`, which makes printing a dictionary with many of these values unreadable.

I want to be able to write `print Enzyme_dict` and have it print all of the machine-rounded floating point values as `.200` or something, instead of the unwieldy `0.20000000000000001`. How can I do this?

When I try to format the `__repr__` output within the class itself with `%.3f`, it tells me I can't do that because I'm trying to format a dictionary as a float (which makes sense). I would also like to keep those values that I'm trying to truncate as floats, and not turn them into strings.

I'm running python 2.6.6. Thank you for the help!

```
import random
random.seed(5)

numb_unique_chem = 10
numb_rxns = 10
numb_sub = 2
numb_prod = 2
E_pool_size_initial = 3 
numb_rxns_cat_initial = 5

class Enzyme(object):
    def __init__(self,rxns_cat,specif):
        self._rxns_cat = rxns_cat   
        self._specif = specif       
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Rxns catalyzed: %s, Specificity: %s \n" %(self._rxns_cat, self._specif)

Enzyme_dict = {}

R_pool_size = 10 # Rxn pool size, dictated by the input above
for ID in range(E_pool_size_initial):
    Enzyme_dict[ID] = Enzyme([],{}) 
    Enzyme_dict[ID]._rxns_cat = random.sample([n for n in range(10)],numb_rxns_cat_initial)

    Enzyme_dict[ID]._specif = {}
    for i in Enzyme_dict[ID]._rxns_cat:
        Enzyme_dict[ID]._specif[i] = (1.0/len(Enzyme_dict[ID]._rxns_cat))

print Enzyme_dict
```

Comment: Why not just iterate through the dictionary `.items()` and format and print each key/value pair yourself?

Comment: You don't want to format the *dictionary* as 3 d.p. `float`, you want to format its *values* that way. Also, `__repr__` shouldn't be used like that, use `__str__` - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python

Comment: I can't reproduce it in python 2.7.6: `python -c 'print repr(1.0/5)'` prints `0.2`. Is upgrading an option? (I would highly recommend it, 2.7.6 is a huge improvement.) You may also try to `round(1.0/len(Enzyme_dict[ID]._rxns_cat), 3)`

Comment: @OdraEncoded I guess I don't have a good answer for that besides the fact that I was looking for simplicity.

Comment: @jonsharpe Right, so it seems to me I would have to change the 2nd-to-last line of code. I could format it as a string and have it print off the right number of decimals, but I would like to keep as a float if possible. Thanks for the note about `__str__`

Comment: @m.wasowski Hmm that's good to know. I will look into upgrading. On 2.6, using the round function like you suggested still gives `0.20000000000000001`

Comment: @m.wasowski it is indeed a change from 2.6 to 2.7: ["The repr() of a float x is shorter in many cases: it’s now based on the shortest decimal string that’s guaranteed to round back to x."](https://docs.python.org/2.7/whatsnew/2.7.html#python-3-1-features)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As OdraEncoded suggested, you can simply tweak your **repr**() method to print the following:

```
def __repr__(self):
        return "Rxns catalyzed: %s, Specificity: %s \n" %(self._rxns_cat, ['%.3f' % spec for spec in self._specif])
```